# Sterilize Chrome JSON Bookmarks

Tags: c#, json, google-chrome, json.net

I am trying to programmatically add bookmarks to Chrome's bookmarks file. It is stored in the JSON format, and I am using JSON.Net to desteralize it. [Here](http://pastebin.com/N6aBaqf2) is the code I use to desterilize it, if it helps. After each bookmark is read, it is stored in my Bookmark class.

```
public class Bookmark
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string browser { get; set; }
    public DateTime added { get; set; }
    public string fullPath { get; set; }
    public object currentPath { get; set; }
    public Bookmark(string url, string title, string browser, DateTime added, string fullPath, object currentPath = null)
    {
        this.url = url;
        this.title = title;
        this.browser = browser;
        this.added = added;
        this.fullPath = fullPath;
        this.currentPath = currentPath;
    }
```

Now, the issue comes when I try to sterilize my bookmarks and store them in Chrome's bookmark file. When I attempt to desterilize this, I run into an issue with lists, for in my class, each folder can only have one URL or folder as a child, however, I am not sure of how you implement that. I also believe that in order for this to work, you must have some way of checking the current folder and see if it is the same as the last folder, and again, I am unsure of how this may work.

Here is the expected output:

```
"children": [ {
    "children": [ {
       "children": [ {
          "date_added": "12995911618983970",
          "id": "8",
          "name": "NestedNestedURL",
          "type": "url",
          "url": "http://url.com/"
       } ],
       "date_added": "12995911579845538",
       "date_modified": "12995911618983970",
       "id": "5",
       "name": "NestedNestedFolder",
       "type": "folder"
    }, {
       "date_added": "12995911609609970",
       "id": "7",
       "name": "NestedURL",
       "type": "url",
       "url": "http://url.com/"
    } ],
    "date_added": "12995911570603538",
    "date_modified": "12995911609609970",
    "id": "4",
    "name": "NestedFolder",
    "type": "folder"
 }, {
    "children": [ {
       "date_added": "12995911631570970",
       "id": "9",
       "name": "NestedURL2",
       "type": "url",
       "url": "http://url.com/"
    } ],
    "date_added": "12995911589790970",
    "date_modified": "12995911631570970",
    "id": "6",
    "name": "NestedFolder2",
    "type": "folder"
 }
```

And here is the incorrect output I recieve with my current code:

```
"children": [
  {
    "children": {
      "date_added": 12995893609609970,
      "id": 0,
      "name": "NestedURL",
      "type": "url",
      "url": "http://url.com/"
    },
    "date_added": 12995893609609970,
    "date_modified": 0,
    "id": 0,
    "name": "NestedFolder",
    "type": "folder"
  },
  {
    "children": {
      "date_added": 12995893618983970,
      "id": 1,
      "name": "NestedNestedURL",
      "type": "url",
      "url": "http://url.com/"
    },
    "date_added": 12995893618983970,
    "date_modified": 0,
    "id": 1,
    "name": "NestedFolder",
    "type": "folder"
  },
  {
    "children": {
      "date_added": 12995893631570970,
      "id": 2,
      "name": "NestedURL2",
      "type": "url",
      "url": "http://url.com/"
    },
    "date_added": 12995893631570970,
    "date_modified": 0,
    "id": 2,
    "name": "NestedFolder2",
    "type": "folder"
  }
```

I am using this code: All of the classes are for JSON sterilization. Like I said, I believe something must be changed with my Folder class.

```
public void Sync()
{
    Browser browser = new Chrome();
    SortableBindingList<Bookmark> marks = browser.ReturnBookmarks();
    SortableBindingList<object> newmarks = new SortableBindingList<object>();
    int count = 0;
   newmarks.Add(new json_top());
    json_top top = newmarks[0] as json_top;

    top.roots = new json_root();
    List<object> roots = new List<object>();

    Folder bookmarks_bar = new Folder();
    Folder other = new Folder();
    List<Object> barlist = new List<Object>();
    List<object> otherlist = new List<object>();
    List<object> children = new List<object>();
    List<string> existingFolders = new List<string>();

    bookmarks_bar.date_added = ToChromeTime(marks[0].added);
    bookmarks_bar.name = "Bookmarks bar";
    other.date_added = ToChromeTime(marks[0].added);
    other.name = "Other bookmarks";

    bool isBookmarkBar = true;

    Folder folder = new Folder();
    foreach (Bookmark mark in ordered)
    {
        List<string> fullpathlist = mark.fullPath.Split('\\').ToList();
        int count1 = 0;
        if (currentPath != mark.fullPath)
        {
            folder = (createFolder(fullpathlist, fullpathlist[0], mark));
            folder.children = (setChild(fullpathlist, folder, mark, 1));
            count++;
        }
        json_URL u = new json_URL();
        u.date_added = ToChromeTime(mark.added);
        u.id = id;
        u.name = mark.title;
        u.url = mark.url;
        folder.children=(u);
        if(isBookmarkBar)
            barlist.Add(folder);
        else
        {
            otherlist.Add(folder);
        }
    }
    bookmarks_bar.children = barlist;
    other.children = otherlist;
    top.roots.bookmark_bar = (bookmarks_bar);
    top.roots.other = other;
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newmarks, Formatting.Indented);
    File.WriteAllText(@"c:\person.json", json);
}

    Folder setChild(List<string> fullPathList, Folder parent, Bookmark mark, int count )
    {
        if (count < fullPathList.Count)
        {
            Folder child = new Folder();
            child.date_added = ToChromeTime(mark.added);
            child.id = id;
            child.name = fullPathList[count];
            Folder LIST = setChild(fullPathList, child, mark, count + 1);
            child.children= LIST;
            return child;
        }            
    }

        class json_root
        {
            public Folder bookmark_bar { get; set; }
            public Folder other { get; set; }
        }

        class json_top
        {
           public string checksum { get { return ""; } }
           public json_root roots { get; set; }
            public int version { get { return 1; } }
        }

        class json_URL : folderAndURL
        {
            public long date_added { get; set; }
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string type { get { return "url"; } }
            public string url { get; set; }
        }

    public class Folder
    {
        public object children { get; set; }
        public long date_added { get; set; }
        public long date_modified
        {
            get { return 0; }
        }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string type
        {
            get { return "folder"; }
        }
    }
```

I need assistance in making my output match my input, so that Chrome can correctly read the bookmark file.

Thanks!